# Discontinuities in heat equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, continuity

Suppose that I have a D dimensional body (line, square or cube) and I apply a heat on the D-1 dimensional boundary of the body (point, line or surface). Inside the body the temperature is $u(\vec{p},t)=0$, but on that boundary there is a certain temperature $u(\vec{p},t)=f(\vec{p})$. Is such a system solvable analytically (or even numerically)?

Comment: Are you saying the only unknown temperature distribution is on the remaining boundary and that is what you want to find? That sounds like some kind of inverse problem (where you are trying to infer the boundary conditions from the solution within the open set it bounds). look up "inverse problems for pdes" maybe?

Comment: I am afraid I might not have been very clear. I would like to know the full funtion $u(\vec{p},t)$ (including values on the bondary), however only the boundary is initially "heated", thus, creating a discontinuity between the boundary and the inside of the set in question.

Comment: For instance, a bar with width 1, one extremity is initially heated to temperature $T_0$ (there area no further exchanges of heat). $u(x,0)={\begin{cases}
 & T_0 \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
 & 0 \text{ if } 1>x>0 
\end{cases}}$

Comment: Again, are you setting the temperature inside the bar to be 0 for all time? Then the only unknown is the temperature of the other end over time which keeps this internal temperature 0 for all time. This is an inverse problem.  More typically, the internal temperature of your bar will evolve according to the heat equation and the boundary conditions set. You don't put it equal to 0 internally.

Comment: For instance, a bar with width 1, one extremity is initially heated to temperature $T_0$ (there are no further exchanges of heat). $u(x,0)=f(x)={\begin{cases}
 & T_0 \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
 & 0 \text{ if } 1>x>0 
\end{cases}}$ 
However, the Fourier coefficient of f(x) is 0, since $2\int_0^1f(x)\cdot sin(m\pi x)dx \Rightarrow 2\int_0^0 T_0 \cdot sin(m\pi x)dx = 0$, which wields u(x,t)=0. Could it be that, despite the initial temperature in the extremity of the bar, the function is simply u(x,t)=0?